# Final redirection of a link, urllib2 and requests failed

Tags: python, redirect

I was trying to build a code to get the final url redirection of some links, I was doing fine until I reached this one: https://redir.lomadee.com/v2/987163d4

All the links I tried to get the final redirection url worked with urllib2 or requests.

> ```
> s = requests.Session()
> r = s.get(link, headers=headers)
> print r.url
> ```

or

> ```
> response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
> print response.geturl()
> ```

Do you guys have a solution for it? I don't really like using Selenium to retrieve this information, it takes to much time.

Comment: what's `lili`? a list of urls?, also I don't see where you are initializing `i`

Comment: Yes, exactly @Dimitry

Comment: Cleaned the code, lili[i] was my array of urls. Changed it for one link now.

Comment: interesting nothing is returning the redirect link, including `httplib`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Yes, it's really weird. I know selenium could do this job, but it is time expensive.

Comment: it doesn't even register as a redirect, `r = requests.get(link) ---> r.is_redirect ---> False`

Comment: Analyzing the **r.content** I found this piece of html:

setTimeout(location.href='https://www.walmart.com.br/dvd-automotivo-pioneer-avh-3880-com-usb-frontal-e-tela-de-7/3820066/pr?utm_term=22696088&utm_campaign=lomadee&utm_medium=afiliados&utm_source=lomadee&lmdsid='+new Date().getTime().toString().slice(8,12)+'29157007', 500)

Comment: Is it sort of javascript running in this website?